# Passing a HTML element with ID

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

my question is about a code combining HTML5 features ContentEditable and localStorage.

Here is my two JS function, one for storing the user edit in the table cell, another for getting the value and pass it to the table cell.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function storeUserEdit(id) {
    var pre_value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem("userEdit",pre_value);
    }
function applyUserEdit() {  
    if (localStorage.getItem("userEdit")){
    var new_value = localStorage.getItem("userEdit");
    }
    document.getElementById('prjSch_row1_col1').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userEdit");
} 
</script>
```

and here these two functions embedded in body content:

...

```
<td id="prjSch_row1_col1" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUserEdit(this.id)" >
</td>
<script>applyUserEdit()</script>
```

...

I want to use this to many table cells in my HTML page and how I can replace prjSch_row1_col1 with id and pass it to function getUserEdit();

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like [this](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable). because what you mention in the question is not enough to me to think about an answer. When do you need to fire `applyUserEdit()` function, on page load or ...

Please let me know enough details.

16/08/2013 >

Very sorry for the delay! Please find the below code which I tested in Firefox. Is this the behavior you want. Please don't test in fiddler. It's not working there, I don't know why.

`

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function storeUserEdit(id) {
            var pre_value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem("userEdit",pre_value);
            localStorage.setItem('userEditControl', id);
        }
        function applyUserEdit(id) {
            var new_value = '';
            if (localStorage.getItem("userEdit")){
                new_value = localStorage.getItem("userEdit");
            }
            if(localStorage.getItem('userEditControl') === id){
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userEdit");
            }
            //this is just to check whether the code is working
            document.getElementById('log').value = document.getElementById('log').value + '\n' + localStorage.getItem("userEdit");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td id="uname" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUserEdit(this.id)" onblur="applyUserEdit(this.id)">value...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td id="pword" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUserEdit(this.id)" onblur="applyUserEdit(this.id)">value...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <textarea multiline="true" id="log"></textarea>
</body>
```

`

Please let me know if you have any issues...

Comment: thank you for your reply. what I want to achieve is different to what you referred in the link. I want to apply the edited value  I want the applyuseredit() run right after fill out each field (table cell). I want to replace   document.getElementById('prjSch_row1_col1').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userEdit"); with  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userEdit"); but it didnt work. any idea?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. it gets close what I want. One little problem, when I finish my edits I need to save a copy of the page as html file. and when I open the saved page, the values entered are not displayed... can you help with that?